# Word Chain based on Codename

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

This is a different format of the famous CODENAMES game. In this game a ONE WORD clue is given which can connect that clue to multiple words. Like a clue "Hand" can connect to words like cards, deliver, body etc.

The following design starts with multiple three word boxes. Those three words are connected to a single word. So three 3 word boxes will give 3 single words which then must be connected to the next single word.

An example is below

[image]

In the first column there are 3 three word boxes. First box (Fire,Date and Game) is then connected to Match. (Matches create Fire, Match.com for dating and Match Game show). Similarly Car,Change and Flat can be connected to TIRE and Mist (Maid of the ---), Serve and Wedding (Maid of honor). Thus now we have the second column of Three words: Match, Tire and Maid which results in the final word RUBBER ( Rubber Match, Rubber Tire and Rubbermaid)

Since it is possible to have multiple word connections I have tried to make this puzzle simple and specific by having not only Blank words but also blank letters within the words. Also provided the word "Indian" connecting to the three words in the last box.

The final word starts and ends in E. Please fill all the blanks.

Hope you like this simple format. Made this first puzzle kind of simple :)

> Hint
>
> I am a bit conflicted on how to give a hint. Several options. But for
> better or worse here is what I picked
>
> The last word is   Eclipse
>
> Now can you work backwords?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer!

Last column:

> OCEAN/NAAN (Graylocke)

2nd Column:

> LIQUID/BUT it could be PROGRAM too (mercury is a computer program,soaps are TV programs, 'Diet program' and Java is a program) CODE, OP says this is SUN

> WALK, ROCK, CAKE

> SPEAK, SIGN

3rd Column:

From Top to Bottom:

> OP says this is JAVA

> MOON

> LANGUAGE (Eclipse is also a computer programme) (thanks to Graylocke for this)

Comment: Any hints, how close am I now?

Comment: Ubj nobhg WNIN va gur guveq pbyhza? Pna lbh jbex onpx gura? Bgure 2 va gur guveq pbyhza ner pbeerpg  ZBBA naq YNATHNTR

Comment: Just worked out cake

Comment: WNIN vf cneg bs Rpyvcfr fbsgjner

Comment: I think I got it now!!

Comment: BX  WNIN vf n YVDHVQ (Pbssrr), Vg vf n cebtenzzvat ynathntr sebz "FHA" Zvpebflfgrzf naq vg vf n PBQR.

FHA tbrf onpx gb TNF, QNAPR naq EBBZ

Comment: Just changed it, I don't think mcgyver is right...

Comment: Will I be awarded the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like parts of this are almost certainly not what was expected (and it also feels like a very strange psychological test!) but perhaps this may encourage some other (better!) answers:

Layer 1:

> MERCURY, SOAP, DIET => LIQUID
>  DRESS, MONKEY, ADDRESS => BUSINESS
>  GAS, DANCE, ROOM => BALL
>
>  SHOE, AWAY, SPACE => BOOT
>  CLIMB, ACID, CLASSIC => MELT
>  TAKE, YELLOW, PAN => PIPE
>
>  ILL, DEVIL, UP => NOTE
>  ROAD, DOCUMENT, WARN => SIGN
>  SPICE, MOVIES, (surely lots of words?) NAAN => INDIAN

Layer 2:

> LIQUID, BUSINESS, BALL => JET
>  BOOT, MELT, PIPE => RUN
>  NOTE, SIGN, INDIAN => LANGUAGE

Layer 3:

> JET, RUN, LANUGAGE => ENGINE